# Alter Table in a Postgres function

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I am executing an `alter table` command and adding a new column with default value it is showing an error.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_function() RETURNS void AS $$
BEGIN
EXECUTE format('ALTER TABLE viminfo ADD COLUMN vimtype character varying(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT (NA), ADD COLUMN vimname character varying(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT (NA)');
END
$$language plpgsql;
```

Error:
ERROR:  column "na" does not exist

What is wrong I am doing here.. Thanks

Comment: Why the `execute`? You can write the DDL statement directly in the function without the use of dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 1):

if you don't quote the string it is understood as object, try this:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_function() RETURNS void AS $$
BEGIN
EXECUTE format('ALTER TABLE viminfo ADD COLUMN vimtype character varying(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT %L, ADD COLUMN vimname character varying(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT %L','NA','NA');
END
$$language plpgsql;
```